# Matlab: Split a Matrix

Tags: matlab

Not sure how to do this and it's really driving me crazy.
I have a large matrix with 3 columns showing:

1. The number of items sold in the year
2. The first year the items were sold
3. The last year the items were sold.

So in the following example, 13 items were sold each year between 2000-2010 and 44 in 2003 and 2004:

```
Matrix_A = {13,    2000,    2010;
            44,    2003,    2004}
```

I'm trying to separate out the values by year to calculate the total number of items sold each year. So, 57 (13 + 44) items will have been sold in 2003 and 2004, and 13 all other years.

The resulting matrix would look like this:

```
{13, 2000;
 13, 2001;
 13, 2002;
 13, 2003;
 13, 2004;
 13, 2005;
 13, 2006;
 13, 2007;
 13, 2008;
 13, 2009; 
 13, 2010;
 44, 2003;
 44, 2004}
```

---

I've tried creating a separate empty matrix for each year, looping through Matrix_A and assigning the row to the appropriate annual matrix. So, for Matrix_A:

- 13 will be added to the matrixes for 2000 to 2010 and,
- 44 to the matrices for 2003 and 2004.

But this seems to involve dynamic variable names, which I can't implement.

In all, I'm lost. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple loop over the datasets that generates the matrix you showed in the question

```
B = [];
A = [13,    2000,    2010;
     44,    2003,    2004];

for i=1:size(A,1)
    years = [A(i,2):A(i,3)]';
    start = size(B, 1);
    B(start+1:start+numel(years),2) = years;
    B(start+1:start+numel(years),1) = A(i,1);
end
B =

      13        2000
      13        2001
      13        2002
      13        2003
      13        2004
      13        2005
      13        2006
      13        2007
      13        2008
      13        2009
      13        2010
      44        2003
      44        2004
```

Comment: Throw those adding blocks in a loop, and this will work for any size of 'A'.

Comment: @Doresoom Sure. I am still not certain what OP needs, so this is just a clean, simple example.

Comment: @angainor, thanks for the response and my apologies for my lack of clarity in the original post. I'm really looking to create a matrix of two columns, where the first column shows the number of items sold in the year (i.e. 13 or 44) and the second column shows the year those items were sold. So, the final matrix would show {13,2000; 13,2001; 13,2002; 13,2003; 13,2004; 13,2005; 13,2006; 13,2007; 13,2008; 13,2009; 13,2010; **44,2003; 44,2004**}

Comment: @angainor - Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. My sanity is restored. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want separate matrix for each year?

You can have an array whose each element represent a year. First element is the first year (minimum of the second column).

EDIT: The same can be done with non-scalar element using `cell`s (see comment below)

Comment: That is very true but I'm really trying to separate out the whole matrix by year. The example I showed here was just for illustrative purposes. My overall matrix is much bigger than this (150 columns) and I eventually need to work out distributions by year, which is why I'm trying to separate it. Apologies for being unclear in my original post.

Comment: In that case, you can use `cell`s. Theses Matlab structures are similar to arrays but can contain anything, including arrays as you need.
See http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/cell.html

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I really appreciate it. I tried using cells but couldn't figure out how to get matlab to add the data to the appropriate cells. So, I had it set up to have a separate cell for each year, and tried to append the data. Is it even possible to have cells of different length? Otherwise, would I not be left with a lot of rows with zero values? Again, thank!

Comment: The content of the cell is an array. An (indirect) method is to extract the array, increase it and re-affect it in the cell.

Comment: Thanks @Clement J. I'll test the method and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATLAB's matrix indexing functionality to accomplish this. This approach should work no matter how many ranges of years or products you have.

```
A = [13,2000,2010;44,2003,2004];
%# grab the earliest year in your matrix
firstYear = min(A(:,2));
%# grab the last year in your matrix
lastYear = max(A(:,3));
%# create a list of all years
years = firstYear:lastYear;
%# initialize the product sum for each year
productTotals = zeros(size(years));
% loop through and add up your totals
for yy = 1:numel(years)
for aa = 1:size(A,1)
%# check to see if the product was sold that year
if years(yy)>=A(aa,2) && years(yy)<=A(aa,3)
productTotals(yy) = productTotals(yy) + A(aa,1);
end
end
end
```